# How to draw star plot with pandas/matplotlib or any other library?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, graph

I have a data set from which I wish to plot the occurrences of an event at a given time. Say an event is occurring on every Monday between 2'o clock to 3'o clock. To visualize such event I came up with below plot.
[image]

Let 'O' be the center and from it each axis(5) originating called day of week and its length will vary individually as the time varies.
On each axis then we mark event with red dots with time as one coordinate.
Time closer to 'O' is start of day and increases with length of axis.

*Much appreciated if you better visualization than above. Thanks*

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the plot you've suggested using polar axes in matplotlib, see https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html.

Remove the radial grid lines and tick labels, and instead plot seven lines at n*(360/7) degrees, to represent the seven days of the week, and then add on your red dots at the relevant radial distances